# Noun emphasizing the cohesivness of a team

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a noun to describe the cohesiveness and unified purpose of a team, rather than just the usual sense of overall talent used when describing a group of individuals as "the best team in the league."

I would like to write a sentence such as:

> They only win the championship when they are the best *X* in the league.

where *X* is the noun that indicates "greatest cohesion" rather than "greatest amount of talent."

Comment: Does it have to be "are the best"? Can it be "have the best"?

Comment: And if a compound noun is a 'noun', _team spirit_ would work after 'has/possess/display' and is the usual term: '**team spirit** noun
feelings of camaraderie among the members of a group, enabling them to cooperate and work well together.' [Google Dictionary as was]

Comment: I would prefer a single-word noun here, rather than a phrase involving the use of "team."

Comment: I generally use the word "team" to mean this.  (Unfortunately, far too many people understand the word differently.)

Comment: Not answering directly as it's a bit of a reword but how about "the most cohesive team"? "Best" is inherently vague so makes it harder for you. There are other options beyond "cohesive", such as "disciplined", "organised", etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not committed to "...they *are* the best X...", you can try ***synergy***.

> They only win the championship when they have the best **synergy** in the league.

**Synergy**: the interaction of elements that when combined produce a total effect that is greater than the sum of the individual elements, contributions, etc.; synergism.

Comment: I must admit that I've come to loathe the word synergy because of its use in modern business, which has largely stripped it of any real consequence.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ***teamwork***.

> *n.* Cooperative effort by the members of a group or team to achieve a common goal. [[TFD]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/teamwork)

To fit *teamwork* in your example, use *have* (or *exhibit, demonstrate, display, bring out* etc.) instead of *are*:

> They only win the championship when they have the best teamwork in the league.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **"operation"**  - in the way one would describe an efficient factory, for instance.

-or-

**"System"** - in a quasi-medical sense of different parts working together to perform a single function.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider "unit" or "collective"